# How do I Change JSON Object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following line in my code. It was generated by my IDE. Basically this line consists of a div which acts as an animated sidebar. The width of the sidebar is represented by the 'v' parameter (set here at 85).

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="inner-element uib_w_5 uib_sidebar rightbar bar-bg thumb-bg bar-gutter" data-uib="layout/right_sidebar" data-ver="1" data-anim="{'style':'overlap', 'v':85, 'side':'right', 'dur':200}">
```

I would like to change the value of 'v' to 250 using a Script Tag.

I tried to insert the following script to overwrite the above data-anim attribute but it did not work.

```js
<script>
 document.getElementById("sidebar").jsonObj['data-anim'] = "{'style':'overlap', 'v':250, 'side':'right', 'dur':200}"
</script>
```

Any ideas as to what's wrong with my `<script>` tag ?

Answer (score 1):

use [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) of the `sidebar` element

it should be

```
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
sidebar.setAttribute( "data-anim" , "{'style':'overlap', 'v':250, 'side':'right', 'dur':200}" );
```

read up [this setAttribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) as well

```js
document.getElementById("sidebar").setAttribute("data-anim", "{'style':'overlap', 'v':250, 'side':'right', 'dur':200}");

var abc = document.getElementById("sidebar").getAttribute("data-anim");

alert(abc);
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="inner-element uib_w_5 uib_sidebar rightbar bar-bg thumb-bg bar-gutter" data-uib="layout/right_sidebar" data-ver="1" data-anim="{'style':'overlap', 'v':85, 'side':'right', 'dur':200}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

Here is the `<script>` that will work:

document.getElementById("sidebar").dataset.anim = "{'style':'overlap', 'v':250, 'side':'right', 'dur':200}";